# Dividing tasks into aws step functions and then join them back when all completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

We have a **AWS step function that processes csv files**. These CSV files records can be anything from 1 to 4000.

Now, I want to create another **inner AWS step function** that will process these csv records. The problem is for each record I need to hit another API and for that I want all of the record to be executed asynchronously.

For example - CSV recieved having records of 2500
The step function called another step function 2500 times (The other step function will take a CSV record as input) process it and then store the result in Dynamo or in any other place.

I have learnt about the callback pattern in aws step function but in my case I will be passing 2500 tokens and I want the outer step function to process them **when all the 2500 records are done processing**.

So my question is this possible using the AWS step function.
If you know any article or guide for me to reference then that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like [dynamic parallelism](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-step-functions-support-for-dynamic-parallelism/) could work:

> To configure a Map state, you define an Iterator, which is a complete sub-workflow. When a Step Functions execution enters a Map state, it will iterate over a JSON array in the state input. For each item, the Map state will execute one sub-workflow, potentially in parallel. When all sub-workflow executions complete, the Map state will return an array containing the output for each item processed by the Iterator.

This keeps the flow all within a single Step Function and allows for easier traceability.

The limiting factor would be the amount of concurrency available ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html)):

> Concurrent iterations may be limited. When this occurs, some iterations will not begin until previous iterations have completed. The likelihood of this occurring increases when your input array has more than 40 items.

One additional thing to be aware of here is cost. You'll easily blow right through the free tier and start incurring actual cost ([link](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/)).

Comment: Thanks, at least this is a starting point. It seems like this will going to solve my problem. Thanks a lot !!